# Remove `data` key from fractal transformed single item

Tags: api, rest, laravel, lumen

I'm using fractal with lumen framework to build an API. It works great but when I return any specific item, it return the result inside a `data` key.

```
{ data : { /** All data **/ }}
```

I understand the use of `data` key in a collection. But I don't feel the necessity of having `data` key in single result. ( Correct me if its a wrong REST convention )

So how can I remove `data` key from single result?

Comment: Just for me to know, why do you need to use fractal, Lumen normally includes a serializer out of the box doesn't it? About your question, you should read this page of the documentation: http://fractal.thephpleague.com/serializers/ it talks about the use of the "data" keyword...

Comment: I'm primarily using fractal for including other relational data. Ex if I'm responding a `book` data, I might also want to have `author` data included in with it. I like how fractal does it. I'm not quit familiar with lumen so I'm not sure if its also possible with lumen.

Anyway - I think you answered what I was looking ( Didn't tried yet ). Can you write that as answer?

Comment: Yes of course I can put it as an answer even if it is not obviously the best ^^ are you using Eloquent to retrieve your models?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `Bootstrap/app.php`can help you to avoid `data`. You can make it as a service provider also.

```
  $app->bind('League\Fractal\Manager', function ($app) {
        $fractal = new \League\Fractal\Manager;

    $serializer = new \League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer();

    $fractal->setSerializer($serializer);

    return $fractal;
});

$app->bind('Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal', function ($app) {
    $fractal = $app->make('\League\Fractal\Manager');

    return new \Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal($fractal);
});
```